# Using XSLT transformation and input, save any changes made by user to initial XML

Tags: xml, xslt, input, save

I have a XML, and i use XSLT transformation to create a html output. Inside transformation i use input

```
<input type="{@Type}" class="form-control" value="{@Value}"></input>
```

In my XML i declared type (boolean, text) and value as attributes of node.

```
<Setting Caption="example" Value="exampleText" Type="text" ></Setting>
```

This work fine, initial value of input is the value from XML node attribute.

Now i want to save any changes made by user.

So if user change the value 'exampleText' from input field how can update my XML file with new value?

Also i have a 'save' button, i want when click this to save all changes.

Answer (score 0):

The XSLT engines built into the browsers can only generate HTML. Once the HTML is generated, they play no further part in how it is handled.

Traditionally, user events (like data being entered in a form or a button being clicked) are usually handled by Javascript code.

But there are better solutions available:

- you could consider using XForms,
- or you could consider using Saxon-JS. Saxon-JS is an XSLT engine that runs in the browser and allows you to process user events using XSLT code; your XSLT code to handle a particular event could generate the new XML file that you want to send back to the server. Saxon-JS doesn't currently have built-in support for invoking an HTTP post request, so that part would still need to be in Javascript, but you can easily invoke a JS function from Saxon-JS.